Can't build Blazor app on Mac OS which works on Windows
I switched from a HP Laptop running Windows 11 to a Mac Book running Sonoma.
My Balzor app is saved on a Git Repositroy.
On the Windows Laptop I am able to build and run the App without errors.
On the new Mac I installed dotnet (8.0.400) and cloned the git repository.
The exact same code that runs perfectly fine on the Windows Laptop throws errors on the Mac.
Executing:
dotnet build
throws the following errors:
[file/path].razor(283,34): error RZ1009: The "@" character must be followed by a ":", "(", or a C# identifier.  If you intended to switch to markup, use an HTML start tag, for example: [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(137,34): error RZ1009: The "@" character must be followed by a ":", "(", or a C# identifier.  If you intended to switch to markup, use an HTML start tag, for example: [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(11,20): error CS0116: Member, wie z. B. Felder, Methoden oder Anweisungen können nicht direkt in einem Namespace enthalten sein. [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(10,27): error CS0116: Member, wie z. B. Felder, Methoden oder Anweisungen können nicht direkt in einem Namespace enthalten sein. [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(9,31): error CS0116: Member, wie z. B. Felder, Methoden oder Anweisungen können nicht direkt in einem Namespace enthalten sein. [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(8,26): error CS0116: Member, wie z. B. Felder, Methoden oder Anweisungen können nicht direkt in einem Namespace enthalten sein. [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(9,20): error CS0116: Member, wie z. B. Felder, Methoden oder Anweisungen können nicht direkt in einem Namespace enthalten sein. [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(8,27): error CS0116: Member, wie z. B. Felder, Methoden oder Anweisungen können nicht direkt in einem Namespace enthalten sein. [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(7,31): error CS0116: Member, wie z. B. Felder, Methoden oder Anweisungen können nicht direkt in einem Namespace enthalten sein. [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(6,26): error CS0116: Member, wie z. B. Felder, Methoden oder Anweisungen können nicht direkt in einem Namespace enthalten sein. [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(9,20): error CS0102: Der Typ "<invalid-global-code>" enthält bereits eine Definition für "CPNAME". [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(8,27): error CS0102: Der Typ "<invalid-global-code>" enthält bereits eine Definition für "CPNAME". [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(7,31): error CS0102: Der Typ "<invalid-global-code>" enthält bereits eine Definition für "CPNAME". [[file/path].csproj]
[file/path].razor(6,26): error CS0102: Der Typ "<invalid-global-code>" enthält bereits eine Definition für "CPNAME". [[file/path].csproj]

(I replaced the filenames with [file/path] and the names of Components with CPNAME)
In order to narrow down the problem I created a new Blazor app on the Mac with the following command:
dotnet new blazor -o BlazorApp
I can build and run this Balzor App without errors.
Any ideas why I'm unable to build the project which I have cloned from the git repository from the working master branch?
Thanks in advance!

I suggest you could try to use dotnet clean dotnet restore dotnet build to see if this error will still exit or not .

I tried this but still does not work.
But I now figured out that if I delete two razor files in my Pages folder I can build the Blazor App. But this doesn't really help. These two files are not special in any way. Just two Pages like all the others. And yes these Pages work perfectly fine on the Windows PC.

Which two pages? Could you please share it?

Just posted the solution. Thanks for your help!

The error was thrown in this line of code:
return (MarkupString)@$"<a href=""{env}"" target=""_blank"">Link</a>";

The @ sign has to be after the $ sign.
return (MarkupString)$@"<a href=""{env}"" target=""_blank"">Link</a>";

But I still don't understand why the first one works when building on Windows but not when using MacOS.
If any one knows why I would welcome your explanation.
